# About stringstreams in C++

Tags: c++, stringstream

While studying for interview questions, I came across this piece of code on the internet:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string complexNumberMultiply(string a, string b) {

        //I initially did it using substring (searching for "+" etc.)
        //But it is super easy using stringstreams

        stringstream aa(a), bb(b), ans;
        int ra, rb, ia, ib;
        char buff;
        aa>>ra>>buff>>ia>>buff;
        bb>>rb>>buff>>ib>>buff;

        ans<<ra*rb-ia*ib<<"+"<<ra*ib+rb*ia<<"i";
        return ans.str();
    }
};
```

This snippet multiplies two input strings represent complex numbers of the form `a+bi`.  Thus, if the input is `1+1i` and `1+1i`, then the output generated by this code is `0+2i` (because `i^2=-1`).

I do understand why stringstreams `aa` and `bb` have been used and how they work; but I fail to understand the role of `char buff`.  Consider the statement:

```
aa>>ra>>buff>>ia>>buff;
```

Here, from the stringstream `aa` we first read the rational part `ra` (then `buff` for a plus "+"?), then the imaginary part `ia` and then the `buff` again (maybe for `\n`?).  Is my understanding correct?  If I remove the buffers though, it works fine for the inputs like `1+2i` but fails where imaginary part is negative like `1+-2i` (yeah, not `1-2i`).

Kindly let me know if my understanding is correct.  Thank you!

Comment: Please stop the comments.  They are not doing anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver, sorry, I couldn't see it the first time I posted them.

Comment: The code is ... I don't want to say wrong, maybe "fragile"? It's horribly broken on handling strings that don't exactly match the expectations, but it can successfully read its own output. It would be better if the char's were read into different values and validated. The first should be '+' and the second should be 'i'. If that's true, then it probably read the complex number correctly. (Also, it's probably silly to do math on the public representation. It probably should work with std::complex, and print out the string only when you want to show it to a human.

Comment: @KennyOstrom, as I mentioned in the first line, it is an _interview question_.  So, the input is _guaranteed_ to be of the given form.  This code won't be released into production, so we can make minor assumptions and some guarantees.

Comment: Did you consider cout'ing  ra, buff, and ia, buff2, to see what goes into them?  perhaps the 4 chars of 1+1i  gives you '1'  '+'  '1'  'i' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost correct.  When you have a string like `1+1i` you have two valid integers and two valid characters.  So `aa>>ra` reads the first integers into `ra` leaving you with `+1i`.  Then `>>buff` reads the character (`+`) into buff leaving `1i` in the stream.  Then `>>ia` reads the next integer and leaves `i` in the stream.  Then `>>buff` consumes the `i` left in the stream.

Generally when doing something like this I like to use a more descriptive variable name.  I like to use `eater` a lot as it implies that I'm just eating the input(throwing it away).  If I know what the input will look like then even more descriptive names are nice like `sign`/`operator`/`imaginary_part`.

Comment: `eater` is a nice suggestion. `buff` is almost misleading.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yeah.  When I see `buff` I expect it is filling a buffer for something, not discarding the input.

Comment: Could you please suggest for the input `1+-2i`?  Here there are two signs `+` and `-`.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela The code the does the same thing.  `1` goes into `ra`.  `buff` eats the `+`.  `ia` gets `-2` and then `buff` eats the `i`.

Comment: Also, when only `1i` remains in the stream, why does `>>ia` read only the integer and not the char `i`?  I mean, why does it distinguish between `1` and `i`?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela because `i` is not a valid integer.  `operator>>` knows you are reading an integer so it sops reading once it hits something that is not valid for an integer.

Comment: @NathanOliver, okay, but given a string like "How are you", `operator>>` extracts individual words (strings) separated by spaces.  Why does it work on integers here?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Like I said `some_stream >> some_int` will read the stream until it encounters something that is not valid for a `int`.  Then it stops there.  All number extraction works this way.

Comment: When extracting something like an integer, where there are obvious boundaries of what constitutes a valid one and what doesn’t, it only reads the valid characters. On a string, to avoid reading the *entire stream* into a single stream, they had to come up with some reasonable stopping place and they chose whitespace as the default. If you want the full details, you can check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get (which is called by the ostream’s `operator>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct. `operator >>` is common for each input stream (ancestor of `std::istream`) and it uses [`std::num_get::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) for integers.

Accoding to stage 2 logic and positive imaginary part `aa >> ra >> rb` will run like this:

```
2 -> accumulated to storage "2" 
     (because 2 matches one of "0123456789abcdefxABCDEFX+-")
+ -> ignored, because "2+" is not valid integer for scanf, so first
     operator >> terminates here
+ -> accumulated to storage "+"
3 -> accumulated to storage "+3"
i -> ignored, because "+3i" is not a valid integer, so we 
     can scan "+3" as integer 3 and put it to rb
```

Negative imaginary part is broken for second integer:

```
+ -> accumulated to storage "+"
- -> "+-" is not a valid scanf, so we should terminate second 
     operator >> while putting 0 to ra because "+" is also is not 
     an integer
```

So by adding explicit reading of single character, you read '+' in 2nd `operator >>` and can read "3" or "-3" correctly in 3rst call to `operator >>`